Isekai manhwa about a duke's villainess daughter with purple eyes and a male lead called the "Ice Cold Prince"
The villainess female lead (FL) either has purple or black hair, I can't remember. The male lead (ML) has black hair and is cold but curious about the FL. She escapes her household, as everyone there hates her, and only has one place that she was raised in that she could trust. She also shows off her powers in front of the king and her so-called family.
She's in a duke's family, but her mother slept with someone else and not "her father" she knows,  and she puts her sister and father in jail for their crimes.
The manhwa is about a reincarnated-into-a-novel villainess who gets shadow powers after cutting her palm, and it went into her hand as she absorbed it. Her family is bad and she has black hair/purple hair and has something to do with the royal family. Once they get to a certain age, they get abilities.
The novel's FL is evil and is the reason that she had to use a crystal to free her powers. The novel's FL talks to a red crystal that she has to obey, and failure is death. The novel's FL is either blonde or pink-haired. The novel's FL acts nice but is planning something evil. Only nobles get powers.

Is this Once Wicked, Always Wicked...?

I am a successful woman in her 30’s excelling at her career. But I guess the tables turn when life seems too perfect. It is just my luck that I woke up as Camilla Elchasis, a character in my favorite novel whose life is filled with trouble. After possessing Camilla’s body, I first need to get rid of my ridiculous fiancé and his mistress who are fooling around in my house. I must also deal with my half-sister and father who wish to kill me. Meanwhile, why is Duke Caliet so obsessed with me? “You started it, so I’ll finish it.”

A woman dies of overwork and is reincarnated in the world of a novel as Lady Camilla Elchasis, the purple-haired heiress of one of the most prestigious families in the Xumalican Empire. Despite this, she feels under pressure, as nobles in this world are expected to manifest powers by adulthood, but she's yet to manifest hers at the age of 23.
She's also just woken up after being unconscious for months due to being poisoned. She suspects her commoner stepfather, Herain, and her younger, strawberry blonde half-sister, Yusria, of being the culprits, so she sneaks out of the house to go and stay with Mrs. Desti, the woman who raised her, and takes a ruby with her as a bargaining chip.
On her way, though, she stumbles upon the black-haired, "cold-blooded Archduke," Eselried Calliet, killing some men in an alleyway with his sword. Believing that he's about to kill her too, she slices her left palm open and clenches the ruby with that hand. This causes her shadow powers to manifest for the first time, killing one of the men who grabbed her from behind.



Later in the story, she displays her powers in front of Emperor Cartizen Xumalican and is formally approved by him as the legitimate heiress of the Elchasis family.



Shortly afterwards, Yusria is reprimanded by a talking red stone for allowing this to happen.
Shortly after that, Camilla has Herain and Yusria arrested for illegal mining operations and her attempted murder. Herain then reveals that Camilla's biological father was a slave, and that Camilla's mother, Freila Elchasis, married him (Herain) while she was still pregnant with Camilla to hide this fact.
You can read the manhwa at POCKET COMICS.
